# How to set permission in AndroidManifest.xml for background location?

Tags: android

I know we should add "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" and "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" permissions and for Android 10 and higher we should add "ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION".

But if my app is going to be published for all versions starting from android 7 to the latest android 12, how would my AndroidManifest file look like? should I add all the 3 above permissions together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding (even unneccessary) permissions will not lead to crashes or bugs (at least as far as I know), so you can and should add those 3 permissions together, if you want to support that wide range of android versions

Comment: tested with no crashes or bugs but i need to make sure before submitting the app to the store and whether i have to do any modification to the file or not. i will publish soon and give it a try. thanks